# How to change acl into case-insensitive in db connector version 3?

Tags: xslt, stylesheet, google-search-appliance

Below is my stylesheet used in database connector v3.Currently all ACl information was case sensitive. I wanted to change it into case insensitive,  also how to add the google:aclusers. Please advice me on this, how to achieve.

```
<xsl:template name="aclTokenizer">     
<xsl:param name="text" />     
    <xsl:param name="separator" select="';'"/>    
     <xsl:choose>        
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">            
         <meta name="google:aclusers" content="{normalize-space($text)}" />         
        </xsl:when>         
        <xsl:otherwise>            
          <meta name="google:aclusers" content="{normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator))}" />            
          <xsl:call-template name="aclTokenizer">                
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>           
          </xsl:call-template>      
         </xsl:otherwise>     
     </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Is this XSLT 2.0 or XSLT 1.0? And what do you mean with case-insensitive, do you want part (which part?) of the output to be in all-caps, or all-small letters? Or is it about the `contains()` of `substring-before` function to do a case-insensitive search?

Comment: HI Abel, Im using 1.0.  Basically what i want, during authorization for my user the result doesnot return my expected document.  When i check the document in index-diagnostic page , under permitted users (Default)::[mydomain]\username(ECS). I suspect it doesnot return the result because of this acl added as a case sensitive for this document.

Comment: Answer to my above question, under v3 db connectors, there is no way to change the case sensitivity pattern.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry, I still have no idea what you are getting at. Please answer in terms of XML and XSLT transformation, or XPath, I have no idea what ECS means, or v3 db connectors, and I don't think it has anything to do with XSLT. If XSLT can be used to solve your issue, show your input XML and the expected output and the output that is (currently) wrong. Note that, anything related to string-manipulation is hard in XSLT 1.0. If you can switch to XSLT 2.0 it will make life simpler.